# Strange image format, fast way to get into image/np array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a camera that sends me back very strange formatted image data that I need to reconstruct into an image quickly.

The data comes back at bytes. Each "line" of the sensor (1024 bytes) is written as 2048 bytes, which makes sense since its a 12-bit resolution image and therefore, needs 2 bytes per pixel.

The strange part is, the first 1024 bytes are the lower 8-bits of the pixels and the second 1024 bytes are the upper 8-bits of the pixels.

so the first byte, byte[0], is the lower-bits of byte[1024]. So the full pixelData would be :

```
byte[1024]*8 + byte[0]
```

this is for each line, and there are 1280 lines to go through for the full sensor.

Is this a known image format and I just dont know about it?

If it's not known, what could be a fast way to get the data into a np/image?

I was thinking I could slice it 1280 ways and then reconstruct each line, but that would take a very long time, especially in python.

Comment: The best way to get an answer is to share your image (using Google Drive or Dropbox or similar) along with everything you know about it - e.g. width, height, colour/mono, bits per sample, link to camera/sensor that recorded it, software that can decode it, known working images...

Comment: No, it should be `bytes[1024]*256+bytes[0]`. A bit is a digit in base 2. If, in base 10, you had said "the first 8 digits are in `bytes[0]`, the last 4 digits in `bytes[1024]`", then you would conclude that you need to compute `bytes[1024]*100000000+bytes[0]`. Because 100000000=10⁸, So, in base 2, it is 2⁸=256.

Comment: Note that this is not really a "image format" problem (as in jpg vs png or tiff debate) rather a "image data transmission protocol". Lot of modern camera confuse both nowadays, because they do encore the image for transmission over the network (sending a flow of jpg, or some rtsp stream). But once upon a time, cameras weren't dealing with format at all. They just send the raw data as come out of their sensor, and then it is up to the computer on the other side to encode that in a given format to store in a file.

Comment: So, there is not many ways to send image data anyway. When it is 8 bits monochrome, usually they just send the W×H bytes. When it is 8 bits trichrome (so 24 bits per pixel, RGB, for example), sometimes they send W×H×3 bytes, sometimes they send 3×W×H bytes (a plane of red, plane of green, plane of blue). That is "XY vs Z". Plus, they could use RGB or BGR order. Or, for alignment purpose, they could use 32 bits (RGBA or BGRA) (which is not for alpha; that is what we do with this extra channel, but camera don't have a alpha sensor). Etc. I mention all that to show you: those are not

Comment: really what you would have called "not strange image format". Simply because nowadays, user is not used to think about that. This is usually done inside the camera driver. User gets either some encoded image or stream, if it is a network camera, or some memory pointer with a W×H×3 array. Without bothering about the ways those W×H×3 bytes came from the camera to the computer. That is why, since you have to deal with the raw data from the camera yourself, any format would have been probably strange to you anyway.

Comment: But that is not really an usual way. Except for the fact that 12bits camera are not that common. But I would compare that to the camera that send RGB images by planes of 3 W×H bytes. They do exist, are not that uncommon. In your case the 2 bytes that compose each W×H pixels are also send by planes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use NumPy to vectorize the decode step, and avoid a loop in Python.

e.g.

```py
decoded = byte[1024:2048] * 256 + byte[0:1024]
```

Would decode one line at a time, rather than one pixel at a time.

Comment: I was going to suggest a bitshift instead of the multiplication but something like `np.left_shift(bytes[1024:2048], 8, dtype='u2') + bytes[:1024]` is actually slower in my tests. Nice to see the simpler solution being faster

Comment: For the whole image I suggest the two-liner: `bytes = bytes.reshape((-1, 2, 1024)); decoded = bytes[:,1] * 256 + bytes[:,0]`